# Pink in memory htop

Tags: linux, monitoring, memory, htop

What does the pink color in memory htop means and how can I reset it?

You can see example here:
[htop preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7H4N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hit F1 and you'll have the information :
[image]